# Using Gson to persist a dynamic List for offline access

Tags: java, android, json, pagination, gson

I have a couple of class `Foo` and `FooContainer`. `Foo` is the `JSONObject` returned from the API I'm fetching from and I use `FooContainer` alongside [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the incoming request.

What I'm unclear about is that the API involves pagination and each time I make a new request, I'm unsure how to save the previously loaded data along with the newest data.

In other words, right now when I save the latest `FooContainer`, none of the previous data is saved along with it. I suppose I'm just unclear on how to effectively use Gson to save all of my data for offline access.

**FooContainer**

```
public class FooContainer {

    public List<Foo> foos;

}
```

**put**

```
public void put(FooContainer fooContainer) {
    final File file = getFileForKey(FOO_CACHE);
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        mGson.toJson(fooContainer, FooContainer.class, new JsonWriter(writer));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        LOGE(TAG, "put - Error adding FooContainer", e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
    }
}
```

**get**

```
public FooContainer get() {
    Reader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFileForKey(FOO_CACHE)));
        return mGson.fromJson(reader, FooContainer.class);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        LOGE(TAG, "get - Error retrieving FooContainer", e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using an [`AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) to fetch the data, which basically just consists of:

```
new Gson().fromJson(reader, FooContainer.class);
```